# Speed issues when connecting two bluetooth 4.0 devices

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-bluetooth

I am writing a bluetooth 4.0 iPhone application. I can successfully connect two devices but when the second device connects I have a significant reduction in speed. How can I improve it?

Comment: Could you please provide more details about what devices you are trying to connect, and what connection parameters you are using? Also, the iOS version used would be interesting.